# Don't trigger WPF animation if bound value is DateTime.MinValue

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have the following XAML code which triggers an animation of the rectangle when the LastDataUpdate field is changed. LastDataUpdate is a DateTime within a class that implements INotifyPropertyChanged. I'd like the animation to NOT run if the LastDataUpdate==DateTime.MinValue. Is there any way I can implement this in the XAML?

```
<Rectangle x:Name="NewDataAnimation" Tag="{Binding Path=LastDataUpdate, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" Opacity="0" Width="5" Height="5" Fill="LawnGreen" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
<Rectangle.Style>
  <Style>
    <Style.Triggers>
      <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Binding.TargetUpdated">
        <EventTrigger.Actions>
          <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
              <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0:0:0" To="1.0" />
              <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0:0:4" From="1.0" To="0.0" BeginTime="0:0:2" />
            </Storyboard>
          </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger.Actions>
      </EventTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>
</Rectangle.Style>
```

Andrew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why, not trigger on the property itself and have a converter determine whether to execute animation?

Below XAML assumes that you create a converter which will evaluate the LastDataUpdate against the value that you don't want. If you set LastDataUpdate to DateTime.MinValue, the animation won't start. As soon as you make a change, the binding will be forced to re-evaluate through PropertyChanged, and will let converter do its decision-making...

```
<Rectangle Opacity="0" Width="5" Height="5" Fill="LawnGreen" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <Rectangle.Style>
        <Style>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="{Binding LastDataUpdate, Converter={StaticResource LastDataUpdateToDoAnimation}}" Value="True" >
                    <Trigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0:0:0" To="1.0" />
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0:0:4" From="1.0" To="0.0" BeginTime="0:0:2" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </Trigger.EnterActions>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Rectangle.Style>
</Rectangle>
```

Comment: I was trying to work it out in XAML and avoid using a Converter. However I'm sure you are right and using a Converter is the best way. Thanks.